# How to disable Silverlight 5 textbox undo/redo

Tags: silverlight-5.0

I simply want to remove the default behaviour in Silverlight 5 textboxes whereby ctrl-z and ctrl-y undo and redo typing. Sadly Silverlight doesn't seem to provide the IsUndoEnabled property as found in WPF.

Answer (score 0):

you can create you'r own TextBox and override OnKeyDown method Like this :

```
public partial class DefaultTextBox : TextBox {
    public DefaultTextBox() {
        InitializeComponent();            
    }

    private bool isUndoEnabled = true;
    public bool IsUndoEnabled {
        get {
            return isUndoEnabled;
        }
        set {
            isUndoEnabled = false;
        }
    }

    protected override void OnKeyDown(KeyEventArgs e) {
        if (!isUndoEnabled) {
            if (Keyboard.Modifiers == ModifierKeys.Control) {
                if (e.Key == Key.Z || e.Key == Key.Y) {
                    e.Handled = true;
                }
            }
        }
        base.OnKeyDown(e);
    }
}
```